# show dialog box when 'New Game' Button is clicked

Tags: android

i m creating a game in which i have got my code of difficulty level in a dialog box but i cant understand how to display the dialog box of difficulty level when the New Game button is Clicked. i have got my code for difficulty level in array.xml and string.xml as well.

```
arrays.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <array name="difficulty">
            <item>@string/novice_label</item>
            <item>@string/easy_label</item>
            <item>@string/medium_label</item>
            <item>@string/guru_label</item>
        </array>
    </resources>
```

strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Brain Training Game</string>
    <string name="main_title">Brain Training Game</string>
    <string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
    <string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
    <string name="about_label">About</string>
    <string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
    <string name="about_title">About Brain Training Game</string>
    <string name="about_text">\
    Brain Training Game is a logic-based number placement puzzle.
    Starting with a partially completed 9x9 grid, the
    objective is to fill the grid so that each
    row, each column, and each of the 3x3 boxes
    (also called <i>blocks</i>) contains the digits
    1 to 9 exactly once</string>
    <string name="new_game_title">Difficulty</string>
    <string name="novice_label">Novice</string>
    <string name="easy_label">Easy</string>
    <string name="medium_label">Medium</string>
    <string name="guru_label">Guru</string>
    </resources>
```

Btg.Java

```
package org.example.btg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class BrainTrainingGame extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

        case R.id.exit_button:
        finish();
        break;

        case R.id.new_button:
        openNewGameDialog();
        break;
        }
    }


    public void openNewGameDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        setTitle(R.string.new_game_title);
        setItems(R.array.difficulty,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                startGame(i);
            }
        })
        .show();
}

    private void startGame(int i){
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " +i);

    }
}
```

thanks for help in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not assigning the `AlertDialog` object to a variable to assign the property methods and `show()` function. Take a look at the documentation here for [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for the differences in your approach:

So when you say

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

it should have a variable to assign this object to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

then you would use the builder object to `setTitle`, `setItems`, and `show`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am not convinced that this code compiles, but maybe that is what your issue is.

The code you are using to create your Dialog is slightly flawed.  You are attempting to use a `AlertDialog.Builder`, but you are not keeping a reference to it, and therefore, are not doing anything with it.  I see two things you can do to alleviate this.

You could remove the semicolons in the first two lines of the `openNewGameDialog()` method, and replace them with a dot operator.  This would fix it because `AlertDialog.Builder` uses chaining (its set methods return `this` so that you can 'chain' multiple methods together).

```
public void openNewGameDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
    .setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
    .setItems(R.array.difficulty,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            startGame(i);
        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Or else you could hold on to the instance and keep calling your setters on the instance.

```
public void openNewGameDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle(R.string.new_game_title);
    builder.setItems(R.array.difficulty,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            startGame(i);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: it worked!!!!!!!! thanks a lot mate :D hmm can you explain me what does every line of FIRST BLOCK of code means to add in comments plzzzzz